# signature field in sencha touch 2 not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am developing app in sencha which having signature pop-up :
I got reference code from this site :
https://market.sencha.com/extensions/signature-pad-field
But When I click on Signature Field I am not able to add my signature over there.
Basically what I want is, When I click on button pop up opens which allow customer signature.
Please provide some guideline or working code.
Thanks.

Comment: what you tried ? post the code..